# Ruby Geocoder multiple reverse geocoders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, reverse-geocoding, rails-geocoder

I need to reverse geocode two locations "from" and "to".

Using the geocoder gem (http://www.rubygeocoder.com/) I've tried:

```
  reverse_geocoded_by :from_lat, :from_long, :address => :from_string      
  reverse_geocoded_by :to_lat, :to_long, :address => :to_string   
  after_validation :reverse_geocode
```

but only the second (to_string) is successfully reverse coded.

Can the geocoder gem support more than one geocoding step?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I banged my head against the wall for a while on this one too.

Try creating your own def:

```
after_validation :reverse_geocode_both
```

...

```
def reverse_geocode_both
    start_coordinates = [self.from_lat, self.from_long]
    end_coordinates = [self.to_lat, self.to_long]
    self.from_string = Geocoder.address(start_coordinates)
    self.to_string = Geocoder.address(end_coordinates)
end
```